# simulate click with javascript by element class not working

Tags: javascript

I have a problem with simulating a click by element class. I found a code for a click on a green button by class name. When you click on it, it goes invisible for 2 seconds and then becomes visible, but it doesn`t click again and i`m tired about it.
you can see what i say :

[image]

```
var elem = document.getElementsByClassName("btn")[0];
    elem.addEventListener('click', function() {
        console.log('clicked')
    }, false);

    var support = true;

    try {
        if (new MouseEvent('click', {bubbles: false}).bubbles !== false) {
            support = false;
        } else if (new MouseEvent('click', {bubbles: true}).bubbles !== true) {
            support = false;
        }
    } catch (e) {
        support = false;
    }

    var refreshIntervalId = setInterval(function() {
        if (support) {
            var event = new MouseEvent('click');
        }else{
            var event = document.createEvent('Event');
            event.initEvent('click', true, true);
        }
        elem.dispatchEvent(event);
    },1);
```

I thing , i need something for check the element then start function again ...
how can i make my code to click my button when it becomes visible ??
any ideas ?

Comment: Okay? Notice that you haven't actually asked a question yet. (And don't fake one by saying "why does this not work" - [code always does exactly what it should, it's your understanding of it that's not working](/help/how-to-ask))

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't using CSS transitions to show and hide the button again?

Comment: it`s very different ! . i edited my question and i put the image of my problem. how can i make my code to click my button when it becomes visible ??

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    $('.element_class').click(function(e){
            //Do something

      //If you want to trigger a click on an element 
      $('.element2_class').trigger( "click" );

});
```

Comment: just a quick note this is in jQuery, he looks to be using pure javascript